# How to listen to Tweets that only contains geo-info from Twitter stream

Tags: api, twitter, stream

I'm trying to use version 2 of the Twitter API to achieve the goal described in the title. Here's what I have tried so far:

- Listening to sample stream (1% of Twitter's stream): Almost all the returned Tweets don't have geo-info when following this approach. And it makes sense, since only 0.85% of all Tweets have geo-info.
- Listening to a filtered stream with only one rule setup, namely the `has:geo` rule. But it's returning the following 2 errors:

  - "Reference to invalid operator 'has:geo'. Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product. (at position 5)".
  - "has/is/lang/sample cannot be used as a standalone operator (at position 1)".

Here's the rule I'm adding to the stream:

```json
[
  {
    "value": "has:geo",
    "tag": "contains geo-info",
  },
]
```

I need help in solving both shown errors, or a suggestion describing a third different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question has been discussed on the Twitter Community forum: https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-listen-to-tweets-that-only-contains-geo-info-from-twitter-stream/162905/2

Short answer:

- The `has:geo`is one of several query operators that can not be used in a standalone fashion, and must be paired with keywords and other non-boolean operators.
- The `has:geo` operator is only available in academic and paid packages.

Comment: This in itself is not an answer. This is a comment referencing an answer.

Comment: My case requires me to not bound the Tweets I'm receiving to a specific location, but to listen to all Tweets from all around the globe that have geo-info. Isn't there a way to achieve this using an elevated access of the Twitter API?