# Issues With Twitter API V2 Elevated Access and has:geo Query Parameter

Tags: twitter, postman, tweets, twitter-search, twitter-api-v2

I have `Elevated` access to the Twitter API V2, and I am working with the API in Postman to search for recent Tweets containing a keyword. I’d like to be able to add a further query parameter to only return Tweets that have a geolocation associated with them. To do this, I am adding the `has:geo` parameter, as shown in the below URL call:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=dogs lang:en -is:retweet has:geo
```

However, this is returning with the following error:

> There were errors processing your request: Reference to invalid operator 'has:geo'. Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product.

From my understanding, of [this page in the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/migrate), the `has:geo` search operator is only available to accounts with Elevated Access to the V2 API (which I have).

If anyone has any suggestions of how I can get around this issue, that would be much appreciated please.

Comment: It _could_ be related to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70179216/how-to-listen-to-tweets-that-only-contains-geo-info-from-twitter-stream#answer-70192219
but I would agree with the OP that the twitter docs do seem to suggest he should be able to do what he is trying to do ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the detail on that page, it further explains:

```
Twitter API v2

- **Essential**: Available when using any Project
- **Elevated**: Available when using a Project with *Academic Research access*
```

I agree that it is not sufficiently clear on that page, unless you re-read it (because "Elevated" and "Academic Research" are technically different access levels for your account).

The answer is that in order to use that search operator, you would need to have Academic Research access, not just Elevated access.